# Filter column with two different schemas in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with three columns; ID, CO_ID and DATA, where the DATA column have two diffrent schemas given below:

```
|ID  |CO_ID |Data
|130 |NA    | [{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 230, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}]
|536 |NA    | [{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 230, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}]   
|518 |NA    | null
|938 |611   | {"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 230, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}                                                                                                                           
|742 |NA    | {"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 230, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}
```

Now I want to create a dataframe of columns ID, CO_ID, NUMBER,ADDRESS and NAME. If no value then value null be filled in NUMBER,ADDRESS and NAME.

First of all I have to filter above dataframe with different schemas, how can I do it?

Comment: What is the type of the data column? It looks like some of the rows are arrays while some are not.

Comment: Yes, Thats only the problem, I have data of diffrent types so how can I deal with that kind of problem?

Comment: Spark does not allow for different types. What is the result of doing `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: See I have csv file in which I have data like this, Now I have to create table with columns above explained.Is there any way to do it?

Comment: schema is showing like this    root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CO_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DATA: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```scala
val df = Seq(
(130, "NA","""[{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 231, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}]"""),
(536, "NA","""[{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 232, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}}]"""),
(518,"NA", null),
(938, "611", """{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 233, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}"""),
(742, "NA", """{"NUMBER":"AW9F","ADDRESS":"PLOT NO. 234, JAIPUR RJ","PHONE":999999999,"NAME":"SACHIN"}"""))
.toDF("ID","CO_ID","Data")


import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_json, array, when, length, lit}

val schema = (new StructType)
   .add("NUMBER", "string", true)
   .add("ADDRESS", "string", true)
   .add("PHONE", "string", true)
   .add("NAME", "string", true)

val df_ar = df.withColumn("json", 
                       when($"data"
                         .startsWith("[{") && $"data".endsWith("}]"), $"data".substr(lit(2), length($"data") - 2))
                         .otherwise($"data")) //checks whether data start with '[{' and ends with '}]' if it does removes []
              .withColumn("json", from_json($"json", schema)) //covert to JSON based on given schema
              .withColumn("number", $"json.NUMBER")
              .withColumn("address", $"json.ADDRESS")
              .withColumn("name", $"json.NAME")

df_ar.select("ID", "CO_ID", "number", "address", "name").show(false)
```

This solution first removes `[]` from the JSON string then applies the given schema converting the string JSON into a StructType column.

Output:

```
+---+-----+------+-----------------------+------+
|ID |CO_ID|number|address                |name  |
+---+-----+------+-----------------------+------+
|130|NA   |AW9F  |PLOT NO. 231, JAIPUR RJ|SACHIN|
|536|NA   |AW9F  |PLOT NO. 232, JAIPUR RJ|SACHIN|
|518|NA   |null  |null                   |null  |
|938|611  |AW9F  |PLOT NO. 233, JAIPUR RJ|SACHIN|
|742|NA   |AW9F  |PLOT NO. 234, JAIPUR RJ|SACHIN|
+---+-----+------+-----------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Alex , but Can I done it without using schema?

Comment: Hello there @Mohammad I believe that without schema you have to process the string directly and that would be very complicated

Comment: If I dont want to use schema then How can I process string directly and how will it complicated?Can you elaborte me little bit?

Comment: You can for instance process each row by extracting the values with regex in combination with a UDF. Although that would certainly be much slower and will affect the performance. So what is the problematic part with the schema you dont have a particular schema as shown in your question?

Comment: Actually in DATA column, there can be many keys , sometimes 5 keys or 4 keys or less or more.

Comment: OK I see @Mohammad but in your question you wrote that you have two schemas only. You need to rewrite your question I guess with a better example this time

Comment: Thanks Alex,Appreciate you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192743/discussion-between-alexandros-biratsis-and-mohammad-sunny).